# Jus Sanguinis Italian Citizenship with Residence in Italy

Tags: visa, resident-permit, citizenship, italy, europe

I currently live in France and I am a not-yet recognised Jus Sanguinis italian citizen. I plan on move to Italy next year for about 4 months for an internship, and I would like to have my italian citizenship recognised while I'm there.

I was born in Brazil and the birth/marriage certificates of me/my family are all from Brazil. My Great-grandfather who was born in Italy never acquired the brazilian nationality and some members of my family already have their citizenship recognised (including one cousin of mine who lives in Rome and recognised it when residing, the same way as I plan to do).

My question here is on the bureaucratic side: If I get the certificates for my family (from Brazil, in full form, and have them translated to italian with certification), should the Italy's consulate in Brazil do some sort of "Validation" of the documents, or the Hague convention would take care of that?

Also, what kind of Visa would I pursue in this case? Should I get a normal visa for internship? Should my employer take any steps on this?